# Radeon Pro Duo low hash rate

Tags: hashrate

Im getting about 43.4 Mh/s on my Radeon Pro Duo using ubuntu and latest fire pro drivers.

Any suggestion on how to increase the hash rate?
Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Memory strapping for one using ATIFlash and Polaris bios editor.

Comment: Please improve your answer to give detailed steps to fix the problem.

Comment: Kindly give an answer with proper details.